# grep a pattern and output non-matching part of line

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I know it is possible to invert grep output with the `-v` flag. Is there a way to only output the non-matching part of the matched line? I ask because I would like to use the return code of grep (which sed won't have). Here's sort of what I've got:

```
tags=$(grep "^$PAT" >/dev/null 2>&1)
[ "$?" -eq 0 ] && echo $tags
```

Comment: Like the inverse of what `-o` does?

Comment: @Steve Prentice yeah something like that. For my purposes, I only need the rest of the line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about using a combination of `grep`, `sed` and `$PIPESTATUS` to get the correct exit-status?

```
$ echo Humans are not proud of their ancestors, and rarely invite
  them round to dinner | grep dinner | sed -n "/dinner/s/dinner//p"
Humans are not proud of their ancestors, and rarely invite them round to 

$ echo $PIPESTATUS[1]
0[1]
```

The members of the `$PIPESTATUS` array hold the exit status of each respective command executed in a pipe. `$PIPESTATUS[0]` holds the exit status of the first command in the pipe, `$PIPESTATUS[1]` the exit status of the second command, and so on.

Comment: That's pretty cool. I had no idea about the $PIPESTATUS. All the below answers were quite good but this is closest to what I wanted.

Answer (score 15):

You could use `sed`:

```
$ sed -n "/$PAT/s/$PAT//p" $file
```

The only problem is that it'll return an exit code of 0 as long as the pattern is good, even if the pattern can't be found.

---

#### Explanation

The `-n` parameter tells `sed` not to print out any lines. Sed's default is to print out all lines of the file. Let's look at each part of the `sed` program in between the slashes. Assume the program is `/1/2/3/4/5`:

1. `/$PAT/`: This says to look for all lines that matches pattern `$PAT` to run your *substitution* command. Otherwise, `sed` would operate on all lines, even if there is no substitution.
2. `/s/`: This says you will be doing a substitution
3. `/$PAT/`: This is the pattern you will be substituting. It's `$PAT`. So, you're searching for lines that contain `$PAT` and then you're going to substitute the pattern for something.
4. `//`: This is what you're substituting for `$PAT`. It is null. Therefore, you're deleting `$PAT` from the line.
5. `/p`: This final `p` says to print out the line.

Thus:

- You tell `sed` not to print out the lines of the file as it processes them.
- You're searching for all lines that contain `$PAT`.
- On these lines, you're using the `s` command (substitution) to remove the pattern.
- You're printing out the line once the pattern is removed from the line.

Comment: thanks, but it would be nice if I could get the exit code. I guess sed never implemented exit codes because it didn't really make sense.

Comment: @Dennis Hodapp: Sed doesn't give you an exit status other than zero because it works even if it didn't edit anything. You could simply do an `if [ -z $tags ]` to test if `$tag` was set. Or, you could pipe `grep` through `sed` and then get the exit status of `grep` via the `$PIPESTATUS` environment variable since it's possible that grep will find something, but there won't be any tag set. I could give a bit more info if I knew what you needed to do. In your original post, `grep` has no file name on the command line. Is the input for `grep` taken from STDOUT?

Comment: My question wasn't very good, and I copied wrong. I forgot to add the input file which was a file with multiple lines. Your answer (with comment) is also exactly what I had in mind. I can't award the answer to 2 people though.

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain what the general form of the above sed syntax is.  i.e., what the hell does `/$pat/s/$pat//p` mean in sed-speak?  How does application of this syntax solve OP's question?

Comment: Ask, and ye shall receive. See explanation above.

Answer (score 2):

Your $tags will never have a value because you send it to /dev/null. Besides from that little problem, there is no input to grep.

```
echo hello |grep "^he" -q ; 
ret=$? ; 
if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; 
then 
echo there is he in hello; 
fi
```

a successful return code is 0.

...here is 1 take at your 'problem':

```
pat="most of "; 
data="The apples are ripe. I will use most of them for jam.";  
echo $data |grep "$pat" -q; 
ret=$?; 
[ $ret -eq 0 ] && echo $data |sed "s/$pat//"
The apples are ripe. I will use them for jam.
```

... exact same thing?:

```
echo The apples are ripe. I will use most of them for jam. | sed ' s/most\ of\ //'
```

It seems to me you have confused the basic concepts. What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: yeah that was bad on my part. I think I copied it in incorrectly, but that's inconsequential. The whole point is to use grep to find a pattern. I want the return code, and then the part of the line not matched.  As I look at it more, there is really no point except to try to write less code (one grep command). Fredrik above seems to have solved my problem in an interesting way but yours also works.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer the title of the question directly instead of considering the detail of the question itself:

"grep a pattern and output non-matching part of line"

The title to this question is important to me because the pattern I am searching for contains characters that sed will assign special meaning to. I want to use grep because I can use -F or --fixed-strings to cause grep to interpret the pattern literally. Unfortunately, sed has no literal option, but both grep and bash have the ability to interpret patterns without considering any special characters.

Note: In my opinion, trying to backslash or escape special characters in a pattern appears complex in code and is unreliable because it is difficult to test. Using tools which are designed to search for literal text leaves me with a comfortable 'that will work' feeling without considering POSIX.

I used both grep and bash to produce the result because bash is slow and my use of fast grep creates a small output from a large input. This code searches for the literal twice, once during grep to quickly extract matching lines and once during =~ to remove the match itself from each line.

```sh
    while IFS= read -r || [[ -n "$RESULT" ]]; do
        if [[ "$REPLY" =~ (.*)("$LITERAL_PATTERN")(.*) ]]; then
            printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        else
            printf "NOT-REFOUND" # should never happen
            exit 1
        fi
    done < <(grep -F "$LITERAL_PATTERN" < "$INPUT_FILE")
```

Explanation:

**IFS=** Reassigning the input field separator is a special prefix for a read statement. Assigning IFS to the empty string causes *read* to accept each line with all spaces and tabs literally until end of line (assuming IFS is default space-tab-newline).

**-r** Tells *read* to accept backslashes in the input stream literally instead of considering them as the start of an escape sequence.

**$REPLY** Is created by *read* to store characters from the input stream. The newline at the end of each line will NOT be in $REPLY.

**|| [[ -n "$REPLY" ]]** The logical or causes the while loop to accept input which is not newline terminated. This does not need to exist because grep always provides a trailing newline for every match. But, I habitually use this in my *read* loops because without it, characters between the last newline and the end of file will be ignored because that causes *read* to fail even though content is successfully read.

**=~ (.*)("$LITERAL_PATTERN")(.*) ]]** Is a standard bash regex test, but anything in quotes in taken as a literal. If I wanted =~ to consider the regex characters in contained in $PATTERN, then I would need to eliminate the double quotes.

**"${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"** Is created by [[ =~ ]] where [0] is the entire match and [N] is the contents of the match in the Nth set of parentheses.

Note: I do not like to reassign stdin to a while loop because it is easy to error and difficult to see what is happening later. I usually create a function for this type of operation which acts typically and expects file_name parameters or reassignment of stdin during the call.